# The minCompileSdk (33) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

error message thrown when I try to run app

[image: error message thrown when I try to run app]

Comment: set min compile to 33 in `build.gradle`

Answer (score 9):

In your `build.gradle` file you have two values `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`

Setting them to 33 should fix the issue.

The code should look like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33 // update This
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.your.app"
        targetSdkVersion 33 // update this too
        // ...
    }
}
```